# Is current Unix epoch in PHP UTC?

Tags: php, unix-timestamp

Is current Unix epoch in PHP UTC? Or it is the local time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, the Unix epoch is in UTC regardless of programming language.

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time:

> The Unix epoch is the time 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970 (or 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z ISO 8601).

Answer (score 2):

The UNIX Epoch is 1/1/1970 UTC as Trott said but for PHP Epoch is in your current timezone.  I use this script to print it out. When I print it out using this script it's always in my current timezone.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("US/Pacific");

print_r(array(
    '$argv' => $argv,
    'strtotime' => strtotime($argv[1]),
    'date' => date("H:i:s m/d/Y", strtotime($argv[1])),
));
```

Here's a link to the PHP source [strtotime()](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/90bb326100e04f56deb27764e5da07074e01888d/ext/date/php_date.c#L1483) and you can read in the function where it's getting the timezone.

```
PHP_FUNCTION(strtotime)
{
    zend_string *times;
    int error1, error2;
    timelib_error_container *error;
    zend_long preset_ts = 0, ts;
    timelib_time *t, *now;
    timelib_tzinfo *tzi;

    ZEND_PARSE_PARAMETERS_START(1, 2)
    Z_PARAM_STR(times)
    Z_PARAM_OPTIONAL
    Z_PARAM_LONG(preset_ts)
    ZEND_PARSE_PARAMETERS_END_EX(RETURN_FALSE);

    tzi = get_timezone_info();

    now = timelib_time_ctor();
    now->tz_info = tzi;
    now->zone_type = TIMELIB_ZONETYPE_ID;
    timelib_unixtime2local(now,
    (ZEND_NUM_ARGS() == 2) ? (timelib_sll) preset_ts : (timelib_sll) time(NULL));

    t = timelib_strtotime(ZSTR_VAL(times), ZSTR_LEN(times), &error,
    DATE_TIMEZONEDB, php_date_parse_tzfile_wrapper);
    error1 = error->error_count;
    timelib_error_container_dtor(error);
    timelib_fill_holes(t, now, TIMELIB_NO_CLONE);
    timelib_update_ts(t, tzi);
    ts = timelib_date_to_int(t, &error2);

    timelib_time_dtor(now);
    timelib_time_dtor(t);

    if (error1 || error2) {
      RETURN_FALSE;
    } else {
      RETURN_LONG(ts);
    }
}
```